# Is it possible to specify build options from within a Dockerfile to control the build process?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, cloud

Consider a the following `docker` command, which builds an image from a Dockerfile:

`docker image build --network host -t test -f Dockerfile .`

Is it possible to specify options of `docker image build` in the Dockerfile instead of the command-line (in this case `--network host`)?

This could be useful, since the host running `docker image build ...` uses a set of fixed flags, which would overriden by custom flags.

Comment: Do you have a specific need to disable Docker networking here?  Why would you want to hard-wire that?  Is there a larger problem you're trying to solve?  (I don't think it's possible, in the same way that the image also can't force host networking without a `docker run` option.)

Comment: I think you can try doing your operations on a docker-compose file.

Comment: @DavidMaze - without `--network=host`, the `RUN` commands aren't able to connect to `localhost`. The documentation on `docker build --network` is extremely sparse; the docs specify it sets the "networking mode". Do you know of other use cases for `docker build --network`?

Answer (score 3):

In general, no.

In this particular case (network access): kinda, actually, using BuildKit, a new build system for Docker.

If you're using BuildKit (`export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`) you can add a comment at the top of the Dockerfile to enable newer syntax. And you can specify different versions of the syntax, which basically works by downloading a new builder, implemented a Docker image.

(A lot more details here: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-buildkit/).

The latest experimental BuildKit syntax has an option for setting network access per build step. Scroll to bottom of https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/dockerfile/ for details, but short version:

1. Add `#syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.2-labs` as first line of Dockerfile.
2. Change `RUN mycommand` to `RUN --network=host mycommand`.